# Android Studio Gradle Project Sync Failure

Tags: android, gradle

I am having problems initializing my new **Android studio 3.1.2**.

I am completely new to Android and I installed **Android Studio 3.1.2**. However, when I run the project I get `Gradle` project **sync** failure.

Here is some build error that I'm seeing:

```
 org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)....."
```

I tried to manually download **Gradle 4.7** and configure the environment variables and **Gradle** settings, but it's still not working.

Comment: Could be an internet connection problem. Are you using an VPN or a Proxy?

Comment: Nope, we don't use Proxy, or VPN.

Comment: Is the URL reachable for you? Can you copy and paste it to your browser and download the file manually?

Comment: After configure u can Sync your gradle and must be check your Offline mode is check or Unchecked @DanielW.

Comment: I think I'm having difficulty connecting to this site "https://jcenter.bintray.com"

Answer (score 0):

**1:** check your Interne connection .

**2:** go to `FIle>Setting>Build Execution,Deployment>Gradle`  and Uncheck `Offline Work`

**3** check your `build.gradle`  file and your repositories must be like below :

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: All the settings you recommended are exactly same as mine. I already have internet connection, but a bit slow one. Moreover, I am also seeing the following error text: "...Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect..."

Comment: @DanielW. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848300/gradle-daemon-for-android-studio-project-cant-start?rq=1
and if you can't solve , say again to help with another methods

Answer (score 0):

Goto "File > Project Structure > SDK Location" menu and Check "Use embedded JDK(recommended)". It may be your JDK version problem.